# How to display error message on the same page in a php?

Tags: php, forms

This is my simple php form script
currently this script show all errors in next page but i want to show errors in signup page how can i do this
i m learning php

```
<?php
// i removed connection code due to mostly code error 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['account']) || empty($_POST['package']) || empty($_POST['Method']) || empty($_POST['TransactionId'])) {
    exit('Please complete the registration form');
}
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, TransactionId FROM payment WHERE username = ?')) {
    //i removed this code due to this error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. if u want this plz let me know"

    } else {
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO payment (username, account, package, Method, TransactionId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['account'], $_POST['package'], $_POST['Method'], $_POST['TransactionId']);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'You have successfully registered, you can now login!';
    } else {
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
$con->close();
?>
```

i want to show this error in same page

```
exit('Please complete the registration form');
```

Comment: To submit a form and display the results on the same page without reloading, you'd need to use [ajax](https://www.keycdn.com/support/ajax-programming)

Comment: Wesley is right, you need asynchronous request in the background to process PHP page without submitting. This is done with Javascript, AJAX.

Comment: but errors in php code how can i show with javascript thanks for reply